# Checking dictionary keys and values

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function,**is_capital(state, city)** that checks if a city is the capital of a state. If it is capital, then it will return true, otherwise, it will return false. If a state or city is not in the dictionary, then it must also return False. Here is the dictionary:

```
    d = {"New South Wales": "Sydney", 
       "Queensland": "Brisbane",
       "South Australia": "Adelaide",
       "Tasmania": "Hobart",
       "Victoria": "Melbourne",
       "Western Australia": "Perth"}
```

Some examples of what I want it to return is:

```
    >>>print(state_capital("Victoria", "Melbourne"))
    True
    >>>print(state_capital("Queensland", "Adelaide"))
    False
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def is_capital(state, city):
    if state not in d:
        return False
    return d[state] == city
```

The first line is the function header. It specifies that the function `is_capital` will take two arguments: `state` and `city`. The second and third lines compose an `if` statement. The third line (the body of the `if` statement) is executed only when the expression in the `if` statement is `True`.

`state not in d` is `True` when `state` is not in the keys of the dictionary `d`.

The final line returns either `True` or `False`, depending on the value of `d[state] == city`. `d[state]` gets the value in the dictionary `d` that is associated with the key `state`.

Answer (score 3):

"Short" answer

```
def is_capital(state,city):
  return d.get(state,None) == city
```

or even shorter (since default is `None`)

```
def is_capital(state,city):
  return d.get(state) == city
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_capital(state, city):
    '''checks whether state in dict keys and city equals to state's corresponding value'''
    return True if state in d and d[state] == city else False
```